# How can I run multiple python files at the same time in Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have been searching and every solution I find is for Windows specific. I am looking for a way to run multiple python programs at one time. I have tried

import test1

import test2

and i only get one of them at a time. I am needing both to be ran at the same time.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "run multiple python programs"? The example you have given will import two modules, and while importing a module does cause the module to be executed, it wouldn't usually be considered "running a program"

Comment: Type `python prog1 &` and hit Enter and it will run in the background, then type `python prog2 &` and it too will run in the background, in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run Python code in parallel, please refer to the module [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def first_import():
    import test1

def second_import():
    import test2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_process = Process(target=first_import)
    second_process = Process(target=second_import)
    first_process.start()
    second_process.start()
    first_process.join()
    second_process.join()
```

Comment: The first paragraph reading through that ' It runs on both Unix and Windows."  I am looking specifically for mac OSX.